# How to extend Chart.js Legend Class?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to extend `Legend` class from `src/plugins/plugin.legend.js` to add pagination feature to it. I tried making a separate plugin only for adding a pagination button, and when the user clicks on it, it displays the legend based on the page number. But it appears like I am repeating the same logic in the custom plugin, with only the pagination code updated.

[image]

I checked the Chart.js source code. The class is being exported from `src/plugins/plugin.legend.js`. However, only the default export of `src/plugins/plugin.legend.js` is exported from `src/plugins/index.js`. Due to which, I am unable to import the `Legend` class. Is it possible to extend the `Legend` class and add pagination functionality?

Comment: I don't understand what setting do you have that has access to source files. User plugins typically start from a distribution, and have one entry point `'chart.js'` (plus `'chart.js/helpers'` if needed); see some examples from the most used ones, [datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/blob/v2.2.0/src/label.js), [zoom](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/v2.0.1/src/index.js), [annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/blob/v3.0.1/src/annotation.js). In that setting, `import {Legend} from 'chart.js'` works.

Comment: @kikon You can check the source code of `Legend` plugin in the `Chart.js` git repo. Yes, I can import `Legend` , but if you see what comes in `Legend`, it is not the `Legend` class, rather it is an `object` with the hooks of plugin

Comment: Yes, I see. Not an elegant solution, but you can access the class as `plugin_legend._element`, where `plugin_legend` is the exported `Legend`

Comment: Yes, I can access the Legend class as `plugin_legend._element`. But its a private property and also it is mentioned that, they are exposing it only for test.

Comment: I don't get what that means, but I don't see any attempt to restrict access to internals in chart.js, on the contrary, there seems a great deal of effort in making it open and intelligible to developers. There's always the much uglier solution to get the constructor of the legend of an actual chart object, including a minimal empty one like `new Chart(document.createElement('canvas'), {}).legend.constructor`.  If you make something great that others will want to use, there will be incentive to improve access in future versions, not restrict it.